# How to generalize and vectorize a LandUseClassification raster file?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, saga, vectorization, land-cover

I want to vectorize that rasterfile with its 6 landuse classes. The classification is very noisy and have to be generalized before.

The result should be a polygone vector file.

I use SAGA, (GRASS) and QGIS.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To simplify the raster it might be worth looking at gdal_sieve, it's available under the "Raster" menu. See: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_sieve.html

N.

Comment: Tryed several times with sieve and majority filter. Best results with sieve! Thanks! I will post the result after its finished...

Comment: gdal_sieve seems to be deprecated for now

Answer (score 5):

To generalize, try running a majority filter. This is available in saga (and grass as well, check markusN his answer).
An explanation for how it works from arcgis:
http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net/shared/geoprocessing/spatial_analyst_tools/majority_filter.htm

Answer (score 3):

you can use gdal_polygonize.py for converting raster to vector, if u previously use .
some information is [here](http://www.compsci.wm.edu/SciClone/documentation/software/geo/gdal-1.9.0/html/gdal_polygonize.html).

> produces a polygon feature layer from a raster
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> gdal_polygonize.py [-o name=value] [-nomask] [-mask filename]
>   raster_file [-b band]
>                   [-q] [-f ogr_format] out_file [layer] [fieldname]

beside this in qgis you can use Polygonize tool for your needs. it is under the `Raster > Conversion > Polygonize (Raster to vector)` menu.

if u dont see anything except Raster Calculater under Raster menu, you have to enter Manage Plugins under Plugins, then enable GdalTools. that is all..

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 3):

You can first use the "mode" operator of [r.neighbors](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/r.neighbors.html) in GRASS GIS (via Sextante plugin), then vectorize with [r.to.vect](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/r.to.vect.html) to obtain polygons.
Perhaps the "mode" operator should be run more than one time.

Answer (score 2):

Using the majority filter with a kernel of 5 by 5 pixels gives the best results for me.

Comment: Please explain your answer in detail.