# How to "clean up" undesired values in a slope raster

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-conversion

I have a reclassified slope raster with 3 values in band 1. My problem is that I want to polygonize this layer, but the surface is so irregular with a lot of plots in terraces and because of this it becomes in a vector layer with infinite polygons.

What can I do to clean up the raster layer to obtain bigger polygons of slope?

Answer (score 1):

Smooth the slope raster first. You can use a focal mean on the raw slope raster and then classify it, which will clean up some of the "noise".

You can clean up the classified raster using a focal majority. Alternately, you could use a sieve approach to establish a minimal mapping unit for your classified raster. Here are some details on sieve.

[Using sieve filter in ERDAS Imagine and/or ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91609/using-sieve-filter-in-erdas-imagine-and-or-arcgis-for-desktop)

[How to generalize and vectorize a LandUseClassification raster file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31591/how-to-generalize-and-vectorize-a-landuseclassification-raster-file)